# Bitwise XOR used as signature

Tags: erc-721

In a sample ERC721 contract linked from a [loom-network medium post](https://medium.com/loom-network/how-to-code-your-own-cryptokitties-style-game-on-ethereum-7c8ac86a4eb3), I saw this code:

```
bytes4 constant InterfaceSignature_ERC721 =
    bytes4(keccak256('name()')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('symbol()')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('totalSupply()')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('ownerOf(uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('approve(address,uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('transfer(address,uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('tokensOfOwner(address)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('tokenMetadata(uint256,string)'));
```

Why is the bitwise XOR (`^`) operation used to join these values together?

I understand this is a cheap and efficient way to "mix" all of these hashes together, but I'm not sure if this is "safe" in terms of collisions and other weirdness, is this standard practice or just a simple hack to arrive at a *probably-safe* "unique" signature?

Code source: Line 481 on https://ethfiddle.com/09YbyJRfiI

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR.

Comment: FYI, that is *NOT* the final ERC-721 function signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a probably-secure method, but after googling around a while, it seems XOR is generally considered "good enough".

This stackoverflow answer has a lot of discussion on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes

I'd really like to read an academic paper on strategies for combining hashes, if someone can find one.

Comment: hash(json(stuff)) is how you actually combine hashes. In other words, you hash combines rather than combining hashes.

Comment: Any XOR combination of hashes will be vulnerable to a quadratic field sieve attack. This was well known when designing ERC-165 (which is the signature technique shown in the question).

Answer (score 3):

Please see Standard Interface Detection in ERC-165. (I'm an author on that.)

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md

The definition is:

> We define the interface identifier as the XOR of all function selectors in the interface.

Comment: Thanks! This is not a danger in any way to have a collision or something like that?

Comment: There WILL be collisions eventually for sure. This is a known problem which standards writers will address when it actually comes up.

Comment: Correction: the actual contract authors will address the problem, the standards writers will merely document the solutions ex post facto :-). I'm getting involved with https://ethereum-magicians.org so I should be more careful when talking about this stuff :-).